# Email alert sends email when lastwritetime is current

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email when lastwritetime is more than 16 minutes. This is basically saying that the file has not received an updated image during the previous cycle.  My email is sending emails 16 minutes later even when the image has been updated.  Here is my code that I am working with.

```
string files = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\ChicagoSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files1 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\ChicagoSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files2 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\IndianaSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files3 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\IndianaSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files4 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\DetroitSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files5 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\MichiganSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files6 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\LansingSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files7 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\MinnesotaSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";
string files8 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\HoustonSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png\";

var FilePaths = new List<string>();

FilePaths.Add(files);
FilePaths.Add(files1);
FilePaths.Add(files2);
FilePaths.Add(files3);
FilePaths.Add(files4);
FilePaths.Add(files5);
FilePaths.Add(files6);
FilePaths.Add(files7);
FilePaths.Add(files8);

try
{
    foreach (string file in FilePaths)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("ScreenScrape.png");
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-16))
        {
            client.Send(CyclopsCentral);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its _very_ hard to tell what you are trying to do from that code.  Is this all in one function?  Why arent you doing anything with `file` in your loop?

Comment: Have you checked that you are checking the correct files? You aren't using `file` at all.  I'm also not sure about the last backslash in your file paths

Comment: what is a DateTimeKind of LastWriteTime? Utc, Local, Unspecified? It is wrong to compare DateTime in a way you did without making sure Kind is the same

Comment: DateTimeKind would be local time or system time.  It would look at the lastwritetime of the file folder on that system.  As far as the foreach statement how am I not using the filepaths?