# Alert email not working correctly

Tags: c#

I am trying to send an email when the lastwritetime is more than 16 minutes.  I want to loop through my files and check lastwritetime.  When more than 16 minutes old send an email alert.  I am looking to use the local or system time where the images are stored.  I have gotten this far, but the system emails too often and it does not alert when I run a test and the images have not updated.  What am I doing wrong?

```
try
{
    string files = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\ChicagoSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files1 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\ChicagoSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files2 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\IndianaSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files3 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\IndianaSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files4 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\DetroitSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files5 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\MichiganSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files6 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\LansingSkyvision\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files7 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\MinnesotaSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";
    string files8 = @"\\cyclops-ch2-10\users\!SptEntEng\Desktop\ScreenScrapes\HoustonSeachange\ScreenScrape\ScreenScrape.png";

    var FilePaths = new List<string>();
    FilePaths.Add(files);
    FilePaths.Add(files1);
    FilePaths.Add(files2);
    FilePaths.Add(files3);
    FilePaths.Add(files4);
    FilePaths.Add(files5);
    FilePaths.Add(files6);
    FilePaths.Add(files7);
    FilePaths.Add(files8);

    foreach (string file in FilePaths)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("ScreenScrape.png");
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(16))
        {
            client.Send(CyclopsCentral);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks identical to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600276/email-alert-sends-email-when-lastwritetime-is-current)

Comment: Did you debug by the way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email alert sends email when lastwritetime is current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600276/email-alert-sends-email-when-lastwritetime-is-current)

Comment: I debugged this and it continued the same behavior.

Comment: I've marked the previous question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 4):

Your check will always be true as you are comparing to future time.

```
 if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(16))
```

You need to change it to -16

```
 if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-16))
```

Comment: Ironically, in the [identical previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600276/email-alert-sends-email-when-lastwritetime-is-current) the code **was** `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-16)`